# How do I mock HTTP calls in Angular?

Tags: angular, mocking

My objective is **not** to write unit or integration tests but to build a demo app that show cases components that calls different endpoint URLs that uses HttpClient module. I want to mock those endpoint URLs without building a backend server such as node Express as we want this to run purely on NGINX and independent.

Is HttpClientTestingModule the right module to use? It seems meant for writing test cases or perhaps I just don't know how to use it for building demo apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating fake backends, you can certainly make use of `HttpInterceptor`.

This link will help you: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/07/18/angular-10-fake-backend-example-for-backendless-development

Answer (score 1):

You could use In-memory Web API to simulate a backend. Check the tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#simulate-a-data-server where you can install `angular-in-memory-web-api`. Just remember to remove it when you actually start using a backend, as this will interfere with that.

I would though prefer to mimic backend calls with observables (or the HttpInterceptor  like mentioned in other answer).

When you would move to actually using an API all methods would exist, you would just change to use `HttpClient` instead.

So getting for example a list of items, you could just use `of` rxjs operator, so something like this:

Service:

```
myData = [{id: 1, name: 'one'}] as MyType[];

getData() {
  return of(this.myData);
}
```

in component you would subscribe to this, I prefer async pipe in template.

Comment: This is good but quite some magic is in place. Doesn't explain how HTTP requests get handled by the in-memory DB and assumes it by pattern which may not work if you deviate from it. Also if you have multiple collections, how does it associate the requests to in-memory collections?